# Iframe load delay error

Tags: iframe, delay

I added a google map into an html page did I take it as a php iframe page but the delay is happening and opens the way errors

```
<div class="iframe-rwd">
 <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="map/map.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what errors you are getting?

Comment: Some features of the map does not work
The central feature of such

I was done with JavaScript timeout, but is there a different way?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You should probably show some more code, maybe the bit where you do the timeout and initialize the map?

Comment: I'm loading a page with the iframe.
loading delay is the problem, and sometimes does not work properly.
I'm handling this error SetTimeout but is there no other way?

Comment: I still don't understand - what exactly is causing the delay, and how does setTimeout help fix it? You really need to show the relevant code from `map.html`

Comment: http://ideone.com/aIZ6fA <---(map.html page)
for example, the map center property does not work